# Page reloading on form submit, getElementById returns null, form not working

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, getelementbyid, arrayobject

The code is supposed to take data from the form using IDs, and store it in an array object called studRec. However, this must be all done on the clientside, thus the page has to preserve the data, to be used for other functions.

I've tried adding return false; it does nothing.

```
<script>
var studRec = [];
            document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", save); 
            document.getElementById("verify").addEventListener("click", ver);
            function save(){
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("fsubj");

                studRec[studRec.length] =  {
                    section: document.getElementbyId("section").value,
                    name: document.getElementbyId("name").value,
                    gender: document.getElementbyId("gender").value,
                    age: document.getElementbyId("Age").value,
                    subjects: x 
                }
                console.log(studRec);
            }
</script>
```

It should log into the console the info put into the forms.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `save` method to accept a single input argument, that being the event instance passed click event, and then use `preventDefault`:

```
function save(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
}
```

See [here for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Complete answer:

```
var studRec = [];
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", save); 
document.getElementById("verify").addEventListener("click", ver);
function save(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("fsubj");

  studRec[studRec.length] =  {
      section: document.getElementbyId("section").value,
      name: document.getElementbyId("name").value,
      gender: document.getElementbyId("gender").value,
      age: document.getElementbyId("Age").value,
      subjects: x 
  }
  console.log(studRec);
}
```

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: @UrielOrpilla can you confirm the above **complete answer** resolves your question?

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstanding, but I meant how do I insert e into the code?
It says in the console that e is not defined. How do I define e, if that is the case?

Comment: That is strange, as it works as expected for me; see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/1rw55xz7l3?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14) for basic example. Open the console to see passed `Event` instance being logged when the red div is clicked.